# Maats Laraval Excel: Can you export with multiple queries?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I have gone through the docs and also Googled. I see little mention of returning multiple queries on the same sheet from Maat's Laravel Excel. I presume therefore it is 1 query for 1 downloaded spreadsheet. I also presume that if you do have multiple queries that you will need to place each query on an additional sheet.

Have got this right ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a perfect world, every query would get its own sheet. But in reality, it will export whatever you give it so long as it receives a single array or collection for the output, depending on your configuration. It would be up to you to determine how to combine your queries into a format that could be interpreted as rows and columns.

Basic example with two queries:

```php
class ExportSample implements FromCollection
{
    // ...

    public function collection()
    {
        // query 1
        $a = User::where('id',2)->get();

        // query 2
        $b = User::where('id',4)->get();

        // merge collections
        return $a->merge($b);
    }    
}
```

Of course, if your queries result in different column structures, there may be additional obstacles.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I discovered the merge approach after posting and found that in my use cases it will not work, as one query aggregates the values in a 'GroupBy', but in the other query they are not aggregated. And so, the merged collection does not work in both cases.   Essentially what I am trying to do is when the user clicks the single  "report" link, it delivers somehow, two data sets.  They are related, but different. btw - with a name like Matticustard and your BIO, my bet is you could be Matt Stauffer in disguise :o)   If you get a brain wave please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Ha! Flattered, but not Matt Stauffer. It's certainly possible to have a single report link that returns one file with multiple sheets, or even everything on a single sheet. The output is only limited by the amount of effort you're willing to put into organizing your data into rows and columns. A mock-up of your desired output would go a long way toward offering more specific thoughts on how you could proceed.

Comment: This is quite tricky on SO. Things would be easier if you have an account on Laracasts. Nevrtheless, I  have provided a screen shot of a spreadsheet table with some info. Here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G-9HkCLipoykP1tnDvVjAndjVi6H5lOW/view?usp=sharing

The table in green works and is in place. I can't really change this as this is what the user demands. You will notice that the values of the children are aggregated eg Morgan and Sarah.  The table below is what I need. You will notice the values are not aggregated for Sarah and Morgan. There in lies one of the problems. Many thanks!!!

Comment: To do what is seen in the image, you must manually generate the table structure. I put together a simple Gist which demonstrates this concept. It's easier to understand with arrays, so I changed the export method. I guessed at some of the variable names, but I think you'll get the idea. https://gist.github.com/matticustard/53cab46a9085c2f46785434045f78745

Comment: You are a rock star! Thank you very much. It being Sunday, the wife has all kinds of stuff I need to do, so  I will give this a good look tomorrow. With you being in the top 6% of SO, you should be on Laracasts on the top of the leader board! You will see me there. I'll give you feed back tomorrow. Many thanks !

Comment: Finally got to your code. Added long comment and code to Github. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I added one more snippet in the comments on Github based on your desire for totals.

Comment: not sure if github automatically sends notifications, so letting you know I posted there.

Comment: Replied. I do get notifications from GitHub. If you do as well, we can stop notifying each other here. Thanks.